# Overflow-x on touchpad chrome windows

Tags: javascript, html, css

A `<div>` with a overflow-x requires you to click on the div before the touchpad/mouse-wheel will scroll the contents in the div.

This behaviour only happens on Windows-based including Chrome.

How can you enable this on page load for a particular `<div>`

Tried simulating a click on element
Tried simulating an initial scroll
Tried focusing the div

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to set the tabindex to -1 which allows the div to be programmatically focused. The on the mount of the component set the div focus.

`document.getElementById("#whatever").focus()`